# How to run two shell scripts at startup?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

I am working with Ubuntu 16.04 and I have two shell scripts:

1. run_roscore.sh : This one fires up a roscore in one terminal.
2. run_detection_node.sh : This one starts an object detection node in another terminal and should start up once *run_roscore.sh* has initialized the roscore.

I need both the scripts to execute as soon as the system boots up.

I made both scripts executable and then added the following command to cron:
`@reboot /path/to/run_roscore.sh; /path/to/run_detection_node.sh`, but it is not running.

I have also tried adding both scripts to the *Startup Applications* using this command for roscore: `sh /path/to/run_roscore.sh` and following command for detection node: `sh /path/to/run_detection_node.sh`. And it still does not work.

How do I get these scripts to run?

EDIT: I used the following command to see the system log for the CRON process: `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` and got the following output:

`CRON[570]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`.

So I installed MTA and then systemlog shows:
`CRON[597]: (nvidia) CMD (/path/to/run_roscore.sh; /path/to/run_detection_node.sh)`

I am still not able to see the output (which is supposed to be a camera stream with detections, as I see it when I run the scripts directly in a terminal). How should I proceed?

Comment: The requirement to run in a terminal sounds like a blocker. There are no terminals available when the system starts up. You need your jobs to run completely headless in order for them to be able to operate without any user interaction or I/O (output to log files only, etc).

Comment: I had no idea what "roscore" is but quick googling got me http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch which seems to be a good replacement for whatever you have in your home-grown shell scripts.

Comment: I added the "terminal" word because I tested them initially using terminal. I don't really care whether they run using terminal or not as long as they are executed at system boot-up.

Comment: Do you get error messages in the system log from the cron job which isn't working? We can't tell what's wrong if we don't know why it fails to run.

Comment: See the [Stack Overflow `cron` tag info page](/tags/cron/info) for a sequence of troubleshooting steps. Once you have verified that yours isn't one of the common and trivial cases, please [edit] your question to show your findings and more detailed diagnostics of where things are going wrong.

Comment: You can use a service (as in systemd): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I got this working eventually, I am gonna answer my own question here.

I did the following steps to get the script running from startup:

- Changed the type of the script from shell to bash (extension `.bash`).
- Changed the shebang statement to be `#!/bin/bash`.
- In Startup Applications, give the command `bash path/to/script` to run the script.

Basically when I changed the shell type from `sh` to `bash`, the script starts running as soon as the system boots up.

Note, in case this helps someone: My intention to have `run_roscore.bash` as a separate script was to run roscore as a background process. One can run it directly from a single script (which is also running the detection node) by having `roscore&` as a command before the rosnode starts. This command will fire up the master as a background process and leave the same terminal open for following commands to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you could install [immortal](https://immortal.run) you could use the `require` option to start in sequence your services, for example, this is could be the [run](https://immortal.run/post/run.yml/) config for `/etc/immortal/script1.yml`:

```
cmd: /path/to/script1
log:
    file: /var/log/script1.log
wait: 1
require:
  - script2
```

And for `/etc/immortal/script2.yml`

```
cmd: /path/to/script2
log:
    file: /var/log/script2.log
```

What this will do it will try to start both scripts on boot time, the first one `script1` will wait 1 second before starting and also wait for `script2` to be up and running, see more about the `wait` and `require` option here: https://immortal.run/post/immortal/

Based on your operating system you will need to configure/setup [immortaldir](https://immortal.run/post/immortaldir/), her is how to do it for Linux: https://immortal.run/post/how-to-install/

Going more deep in the topic of supervisors there are more alternatives here you could find some: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_supervision

Comment: This is probably not a good place to promote a particular [process supervision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_supervision) implementation. Perhaps at least point to the alternatives, and mention that this one seems to be more obscure than the popular ones (at least as measured by Wikipedia visibility).

Comment: @tripleee The question is a very common use case and therefore if there is a tool that could help to solve this problem "easily" and opensource I think always is valuable.

Comment: "Use a supervisor" doesn't really solve the fundamental problem, though it might in some ways be easier than a Cron job, and having the supervisor restart the service if it dies is an additional benefit which is probably useful for this use case. Thanks for the update; with the addition, this is now less problematic to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that "Roscore" (whatever it is) gets started when your Ubuntu starts up then you should start it as a service (not via cron).
See this [question/answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd).